# Regex to match day in month

Tags: regex

I'm trying to edit some existing regexes which tries to extract dates from a piece of text. Since I'm not so proficient with regexes I thought this is a good moment to learn something new.

So I've got a the following regex:

```
r'\b0*[1-9]?[0-9]\b'
```

which (if I understand correctly) retrieves a number beginning with zero or more 0's, followed by zero or more numbers between 1 and 9, and 1 number between 0 and 9. So it matches the following:

```
10
24
01
```

but it also matches the following things (which are obviously not dates)

```
94
0000024
```

while it doesn't match the following (which are in fact dates):

```
1st
3rd
5th
```

So I set out to put in words what I need and tried writing the regex behind it what I came up with:

1. a string starting with either a space, a dash, a slash or nothing at all (i.e. starting directly with the numbers)

   - my attempt:    `\b|-|\/`
2. a total of 1 or 2 numbers in the string. The number(s) together should be between 1 and 31 with either a leading zero or not.

   - my attempt:    `[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]`
3. either followed by "st", "nd", "rd", "th", a dash, a slash or a space.

   - my attempt:    `st|nd|rd|th|-|\/|\b`

Putting this together it would be: `\b|-|\/[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]st|nd|rd|th|-|\/|\b`

But this doesn't seem to work at all. When I test the second part (the numbers) it matches pretty much all numbers I put in.

I don't want to make this a `give me ze code` question, but could anybody help me out by pointing out what I'm doing wrong? I really want to learn use regexes some more.

All tips are welcome!

ps. I know that some months have less days than 31, but I have to start learning somewhere..

[EDIT]

So to make clear (@Saraiva asked for this in the comments). I want it to match the following:

```
01
08
9
28
31
2nd
31st
/31st
-22nd/
/25-
```

but not this:

```
73
01200
026
/2200nd-
(6th
```

Comment: _"which (if I understand correctly) retrieves a number beginning with zero or more 0's, followed by zero or more numbers between 1 and 9, and 1 number between 0 and 9"_ nope, it's `0 (0+ times), [1-9] (0-1 time), [0-9] (1 time) `

Comment: Could you give some samples of dates that it should be matching? like 05/12/2012 or 1st-fev-2015?

Comment: Are these supposed to be at the start of a text string / line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex fragments are correct, you are just making it wrong how to put it all together. If you do this:

```
\b|-|\/[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]st|nd|rd|th|-|\/|\b
```

you are or-ing (`|`) everything (so, you match a word boundary, or a dash, or....).

You want something like this:

```
(?:\b)(([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(st|nd|rd|th)?)(?:\b|\/)
```

so:

```
a word boundary (non capturing)
followed by a number 0-31
followed (eventually) by one of st nd rd th
followed by a word boundary (non capturing) or a slash
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/zM4lI5/3

You may get even better results, if you switch to using look-around:

```
(?<=\b|\/|-)((?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)(?=\b|\/|-)

(?<=\b|\/|-) whatever matches the following, if preceded by this
(?=\b|\/|-)  whatever matched the preceding, if followed by this
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/zM4lI5/4

EDIT:

If you do only want to capture digits, i'd change the rexgex like this, playing with non-capturing groups:

```
(?<=\b|\/|-)([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:st|nd|rd|th)?(?=\b|\/|-)
```

EDIT 2: ok I see that Python requires that look-behind assertions have constant length; in our case, `\b` is 0, while `\/` and `-` are 1 character. If it is good for you, I'd suggest to just use a whitespace instead of the word boundary:

```
(?<=\s|\/|-)([1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:st|nd|rd|th)?(?=\b|\/|-)
```

Sample here: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/J1N5bB) [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mI7bD5/2)

Comment: Wow, you are awesome . The last version indeed seems to be the best so far. Can I also use that look-around for the `st|nd|rd|th` so that the result which I get are only the numbers?

Comment: So I changed it to this: `(?<=\b|\/|-)((?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])?)(?=\b|\/|-|st|nd|rd|th)` which seems to do what I want. I now put it in my Python script: as follows: `re.finditer(DAY_NUM_RE, 'check this: 2nd ')` which gives me an `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. Any idea how I could solve that? Or should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: the fixed-width pattern error you get, is because you cannot you quantifiers in lookarounds, but given your regexp above, it does not seems the case? (actually, it seems supported by python here: https://regex101.com/r/zT6dG1/2). Anyway, not that if you use it like that, it is not correct (the lookahead will be `st OR word boundary`)

Comment: Hmmm, my issue with the fixed-width pattern seems to be somewhere else in my code. I guess it is too off topic to handle that here. Thanks for helping me out so much, I learned a lot from it!

Comment: @kramer65 you more than welcome; anyway, have a peek at edit 2, as python has this constant width limit, on look behinds, not only because of quantifiers but generally (`\b|-` would hit the problem because `\b` is 0 width while - is 1 width).